# Express.js/Passport app creating new session for each request, despite session ID in request headers

Tags: node.js, session, express, session-cookies, passport.js

This has not been noticed before, because for client-server communications, nothing requiring authentication is happening via XHR (as of yet). In implementing some integration tests, I am creating realy requests node-xmlhttprequest to a real instance of the application. User is being authenticated in the first request, and in theory the user's unique identifier and some other pertinent information is stored in session (as I've said, this works just fine for real clients, who do not need to confirm their identity over XHR). For some reason, even though subsequent requests are being fired with the exact same session ID, I am not able to retrieve the session in subsequent requests, and thus can't see that the user is authenticated, and this leads to failing tests where the expected behaviour does not happen, and HTTP 401 UNAUTHORIZED is filling up the terminal.

I've seen a couple of questions which look sort of like this, but that "same session ID" thing does not seem to be present among them.

Do I need to manually add Set-Cookie headers to all XHR requests? That's terrible, there's got to be a better way!

So people like source code, here's some from the test, firing these requests:

```
// Ensure logged in before sending request, to verify that authorized
// users encounter the expected behaviour.
jQuery.post(domain+'/login', {email:'test@express.app', password:'12345678'},
function(data,x,y){
  data.should.equal("true")
  jQuery.ajax({url:domain+'/event', type:"POST",
    name: "TestEvent", location: "TestVille",
    startDate: new Date('2013-09-01'), startTime: '6:45 pm',
    description: "Test Event #1", success: state.success,
    error: state.error, completed: state.completed
  })
})
```

Sign in happens, user ID gets written into session (`req.logIn() should do this, and it does not report any failures), serialization of the user ID does not report any failures, and I am extremely confused as to why subsequent requests using the same session ID are unable to find the serialized user ID.

I am generally not involved with web development, so this may be obvious to some people, but I've been searching for an answer all day and have simply not been able to find one. I'd appreciate any pointers, and am happy to provide as much code as I'm able to, to illustrate what the problem is.

A few additional points of code which may be pertinent:

Serialization/deserialization of user ID (currently implemented in the simplest possible
manner -- This is very early in the initiallization of middleware, after initiallizing passport and passpot.session(). And this works perfectly well for non-XHR requests)

```
// Serialize user for passport session-store
// Currently only serializing 'user_id'
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id)
})

// Deserialize user from session-store to provide
// access to the User instance
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user)
  })
})
```

Authentication of users via the local strategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: "email", passwordField: "password",
    passReqToCallback: true, failureFlash: true
  },
  function(req, email, password, done) {
    User.findByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
      if(user) {
        if(err) console.log(err)
        if(user instanceof UserLocal) {
          user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, match) {
            if(err) console.log(err)
            if(!match) {
              return done(err, false,
                "Username or password is incorrect.")
            }
            return done(null, user)
          })
        } else {
        var msg = "Account registered under " + user.providerName()
                + ", please login using " + user.providerName()
        return done(err, false, msg)
      }
    } else {
      return done(err, false, "Username or password is incorrect.")
    }
  })
})
```

And finally the requests which write to session in the first place:

```
function loginHelper(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureFlash:true,
    failureRedirect: false,
    successRedirect: false 
  },
  function(err, user, info) {
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if(!err) err = {}
      if(req.xhr) {
        console.log(req.session)
        res.status(200).end(err.message || "true")
      } else {
        if(err.message) req.flash('error', err.message)
        else res.redirect('/')
      }
    })
  })(req, res, next)
}
```

I know there are some weird things like sending a status of 200 regardless of the login status, but I can confirm that the serialized user id is written to session on the initial login XHR request, and that it's not deserialized on subsequent XHR requests.

As I believe I mentioned, I am relatively inexperienced in this area, and could very much use a boost. Any assistance whatsoever would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's help me 
First

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneDay }));
```

and update functions to do not trigger database

```
 passport.serializeUser( (user, done) => {
        var sessionUser = { id: user.dataValues.id, fio: user.dataValues.fio, email: user.dataValues.localemail, role: user.dataValues.role, login: user.dataValues.login,  position: user.dataValues.position }
        done(null, sessionUser)
    })

    passport.deserializeUser( (sessionUser, done) => {
        // The sessionUser object is different from the user mongoose collection
        // it's actually req.session.passport.user and comes from the session collection
        done(null, sessionUser)
    })
```

> https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive